# The program puts a series of words from an .csv file into an array, then randomly generates sentences. But it doenst work

Tags: c++, csv

> The program puts a series of words from an .csv file into an array, then randomly generates sentences. But it doenst work.

The problem is that in the first version it does not print the sequence of words on the screen, although it supplies the array with coordinates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>    
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
const int m = 60454; 

int main(){
long n = 0,  numero, i, x;
string firstname, parole[m];
ifstream ip("data.csv");

while(ip.good()){
  getline(ip,firstname,',');
  parole[n] = firstname;


n++;
}
cout << "How long do you want the sentence? ";
cin >> x;
system("cls");
srand(time(NULL));
for(i = 0; i < x; i++);{
    numero = rand()%(m);
    cout << parole[numero] << " ";
 }
ip.close();
}
```

> It's strange because this version that prints them all works:

int main(){

```
 long n = 0, i, x, numero;
 string firstname, parole[m];
 ifstream ip("data.csv");

  while(ip.good()){
 getline(ip,firstname,',');
 parole[n] = firstname;
 n++;
 }
 //cout << "quanto lunga vuoi la frase? ";
 //cin >> x;
 system("cls");
 srand(time(NULL));
 for(i = 0; i < m; i++);{
 //numero = rand()%(m);
 cout << parole[i] << " ";
 }
ip.close();
}
```

Comment: First, do you *really* need a hard array of 60454 `std::string` ? and second, does it have to be local. Finally, you're going to have to do a lot better than "it doesn't work". Clearly, otherwise you wouldn't be here. Elaborate. What *does* it do, and what steps have you taken thus far to debug it. How does what it seems to do differ from what you expect ? And wouldn't you want your modulo to be based on `n` rather than `m`, reflecting the actual number of words read rather than the number you're capable of storing ?

Comment: yes, sorry. I tought tha it was a simple debug question. the problem is that in the first version it does not print the sequence of words on the screen, although it supplies the array with coordinates

Answer (score 1):

You create an array with a lot of elements - 60454.
In the first scenario, you get random numbers from 0 to 60454( it could be 30000 ). parole[30000] could be an empty string, if you don`t have more than 30 000 words in your file. So in the first scenario, you print empty strings.
While in the second scenario, you print all words from 0 to the end.

Solution:

```
for(i = 0; i < x; i++);{
    numero = rand()%(n); // !!! Here use n( the number of words read from the file ) !!!
    cout << parole[numero] << " ";
```

Comment: @david, but it should :) . Sorry, then I don`t see why the second works, but the first does not. Double check everything - the csv file, the code ...

Comment: Keep in mind, that you create 60454 empty strings.
In the beginning of main() do :
for( int i = 0; i < m; ++i )
 parole[i] = "MyEmptyString" : If you see that string on the screen, you know that you print an empty string. Just to test and understand what is happening.